# Unexpected identifier when defining a custom type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

The following code gives me an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on the line `type Player = {` and I don't understand what is incorrect.
Worth mentioning is I am **brand new** to TypeScript, is it possible to do `<script src="static/ts/game.ts"></script>` like you would any JavaScript file, or need I compile it into JavaScript first somehow then refer to the .js file? Maybe that's where I am doing things wrong.

```
type Player = {
    isRolling: boolean;
    position: number;
};

const HUMAN: Player = {
    isRolling: true,
    position: 1
};

const AI: Player = {
    isRolling: false,
    position: 1
};

const PLAYERS: Player[] = [HUMAN,AI];
```

**The only code above that code is:**

```
// - Markers
const MARKER_HUMAN = document.createElement('div');
MARKER_HUMAN.className = 'marker-human';

const MARKER_AI = document.createElement('div');
MARKER_AI.className = 'marker-ai';

// - Dice
const DICE = document.getElementsByClassName('dice')[0];

/* Board Variables */
const BOARD_ROWS = 10;
const BOARD_COLS = BOARD_ROWS;
```

Comment: You cannot load typescript files like that: it will need to be compile into JS first using the typescript compiler `tsc`

Comment: @Terry I suspected that. Would you mind answering the question so I can mark it valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers can only understand `.js` files at the moment: therefore, you cannot load typescript files directly via the `<script>` tags: it will need to be compile into JS first using the typescript compiler `tsc`.

Your IDE probably supports TypeScript compilation, but you need to check the configuration for your particular IDE. Otherwise you can always [compile TypeScript via the command line](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).